# Max value of a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to find the max value of a 3d array in python.
I tried

```
image_file1 = open("lena256x256.bmp","rb")
img_i = PIL.Image.open(image_file1)
pix = numpy.array(img_i);
maxval= max(pix)
```

but i am getting an error

```
 File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    maxval= max(pix)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I cannot catch my mistake here, please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the builtin `max` function that does not understand multidimensional NumPy arrays. You must instead use one of:

- `pix.max()`
- `numpy.max(pix)`
- [`numpy.amax(pix)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

These are also faster than the builtin in the case of 1D NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Max is expecting a single value, the error message should be quite clear, you want to use [`amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) instead.

```
maxval = numpy.amax(pix)
```

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to what georgesl wrote, you can use
`flat` to get an iterator for the array and then do something
like

```
m = reduce(max, ar.flat)
```

Edit: removed the `lambda`, the default `max` should be OK.

Answer (score -3):

The np.max function works for vectors, not matrices (or along an axis). To have the max element a multi-dimensionnal array, you can use `flatten()` : `maxval= pp.max( pix.flatten() )`

Comment: This is not correct. `numpy.max` is an alias to [`numpy.amax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) that understands multidimensional arrays. The OP, however, is not using `numpy.max`.